# Can you add a drop down list to an Android Widget?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, widget

I am looking to Create my first widget for an android app that I am developing. Looking at the documentation i think i can do this but i had an idea that i cannot find anywhere. This is using a drop down box to select something on the widget before clicking on an icon to open the app at the correct page.

With the lack of documentation i am not very hopeful but if anyone can inform me one way of another if this is possible and any tutorials would be much appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the views that can be used can be found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

The Spinner (aka dropdown list) cannot be added inside a widget